# Looping Through Controls Doesn't Find TextBox Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Could you please explain why this doesn't work?

```
    int count = 0;
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox textBox = c as TextBox;
            if (textBox.BackColor == Color.Green)
            {
                count++;

            }
        }
    }
    if (count == 40)
    {
        SchemaForm ff = new SchemaForm();
        ff.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

}
```

It's a test, after all data was checked, i need redirect student to another page. So, i have to check, if all textboxes have green.BackColor and if all of them are, then we proceed to another page.

Comment: What error/exception are you getting here ?

Comment: Does it compile? or a logical error?

Comment: Did you try to debug `this.Controls`?

Comment: no, it doesn't give error, it's just doesn't count anything, count = 0.

Comment: Please learn to use a debugger. Single-step the code and you'll quickly find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. May be there's any `TextBox` missing which doesn't have `Green` color, or might be you've calculated them wrong.

**Edit:**

As you  explained all `TextBoxes` are contained in `GroupBoxes`, so you've to iterate through all `groupBoxes`.

```
bool IsAllGreen = true;
foreach (GroupBox groupBox in this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>()) //get all GroupBoxes
{
    foreach (TextBox textBox in groupBox.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) //Get all Textboxes for every GroupBox
    {
        if (textBox.BackColor != Color.Green)   //if any textbox is not Green, it will not go further
        {
            IsAllGreen = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (IsAllGreen)
{
    SchemaForm ff = new SchemaForm();
    ff.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: I've tested the code, it works fine. Are you sure you're changing the `textBox` backcolor, not the font color?

Comment: if (tbUlesanneKoormusKiirendus.Text == variant.kiirenduskoormus)
            {
                tbUlesanneKoormusKiirendus.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                tbUlesanneKoormusKiirendus.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }

Comment: that's how it changing after check btn earlier

Comment: Is there any `panel`, `group box` or `tab page` which contains the textboxes inside of it?

Comment: yep...i understand now, it didn't see textboxes inside the group box...could you explain how make it see it inside?

Comment: Do you have all the textboxes inside group boxes? Provide a bit info about it, so I could make a proper code example

Comment: I've updated the code to iterate through all the group boxes and textboxes contained by them

Comment: i dont understand. it should work, but it open new worm no matter what. If i set this on button and trying to debug, it show that IsAllGreen is true, but all of them are gray.

Comment: he goes through this  foreach (TextBox textBox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())  and then didn'g go inside, just jumps for new foreach

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in this if statement:

```
if (c is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox textBox = c as TextBox;
            if (textBox.BackColor == Color.Green)
            {
                count++;

            }
        }
```

You probably wanted to check type of it so correct if is:

```
if (typeof(TextBox) == c.GetType()) {
        TextBox textBox = c as TextBox;
        if (textBox.BackColor == Color.Green)
        {
            count++;

        }
}
```

Comment: Did You try debug? Is it entering into if statement? maybe problem is with second if.

Comment: yeah, i see now. it's group box and all the texboxes inside... is it possible to make it go inside?

Comment: Indeed. You need to check if type is GroupBox instaeed of Textbox ,and then if true check for TextBoxes as is now. Just another checking is required. (or better recursive check)